# Fill down formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Is there a way of fill a formula down to the last row dynamically as new lines are added without a script just in the formula in google sheets I need the formula only in the cells with data and not in empty cells so if I have in column B1/B5 1,2,3,4,5 I want in column A1 =B1 and to fill down to row A5 =B5, and only in the first 5 rows and to automatically add the formula in A6 when B6 is filled.

Answer (score 1):

sure, try this in **A1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B<>""; ROW(A1:A); ))
```

or put there whatever you want:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B<>""; B1:B; ))
```

Comment: I did try an array formula but the trouble I had was the sheets are importing data from other sheets and with the array it was considering empty row s not empty and importing the new rows nearly 1000 rows below the last non empty row

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?